# what is the logical OR syntax in JSRender?

Tags: jsrender

i have two boolean variables "IsOwner" and "IsModerator" (ofcourse which can be either true or false) and i tried it as follows **{{if IsOwner || IsModerator}} some code here {{/if}}**. But this seems to be failing... 
is there which i am missing.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks ok, show us more code.

Comment: || is the proper logical OR operator.

Comment: Hi all, got it.... || is correct, but there was some mistake in my implementation....Sorry for the inconviniance...... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `{{if IsOwner || IsModerator}} some code here {{/if}}` is correct and should work fine.